# How do I "push down" the current columns to form the first row, and create new columns to replace that one?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that essentially has the first row that I want as the column row and I'd like to know how to set new columns and set that row as the first row.

For example:

```
|  4  |  3  | dog |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  1  |  2  | cat |
```

I want to change that DataFrame to be:

```
| number_1 | number_2 | animal |
| -------- | -------- | ------ |
|     4    |     3    |   dog  |
|     1    |     2    |   cat  |
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets create a new dataframe with old column row as the first row followed by remaining rows

```
pd.DataFrame([df.columns, *df.values], columns=['num_1', 'num_2', 'animal'])
```

---

```
   num_1  num_2 animal
0      4      3    dog
1      1      2    cat
```

Comment: Thanks this works. Is there any way to do the operations in place without creating a new DataFrame?

Comment: I don't think there is a straight forward way to do inplace op  here since we are modifying the indices of the dataframe its better to create a new dataframe